# New SQL table value won't stay

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am new to dealing with SQL Express DB tables. I have a Windows application that gives the user a textbox that is bound to a value in my dataset (ds) which reflects my SQL table (Specs) field. The user can change the numeric value of the textbox and I can see by setting breakpoints that it created the new value in my dataset (I used *MsgBox(Ds.Specs.Rows(0).Item(10)* to determine this to be true). However, when I open the application back up, the OLD value appears again in the text box. It is like my dataset is not updating the SQL server table.

Again, I am new to SQL tables and allowed the wizard to create all my insert/update/delete statements which appear to be in place. Any idea why my values won't stick?

Thanks.

Comment: Going to need to see some code to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once the element is put in there has to be a database submitChanges() function that has to be called to actually store your new information Im not sure exactly what the command is in VB but in c# its OnItemSubmitt(). Its all .NET so the command should be the same.

Comment: Found out the issue... when I bound the textbox to the datatable, it created a copy of the dataset called ds1. It works now, but any idea why it would do that??? I don't have another similarly-named bindingsource or tableadapter...

Answer (score 0):

In `.NET`, you'll want to be sure to call the function `AcceptChanges()` on the Dataset object. This saves information that has changed since it was loaded or since the last time `AcceptChanges()` was called.

Some information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx) on the function, and an example of its use.